# Data security in Corda

Tags: corda

I have party A and Party B

When I call a flow from PartyA like shown below

```
class TestFlow {
    @InitiatingFlow
    @StartableByRPC
    open class TestFlowInitiator(val Party_B: Party) : FlowLogic<List<StateAndRef<TestState>>>() {


        @Suspendable
        override fun call():List<StateAndRef<BilateralContractState>>{

            val testDataSession =  initiateFlow(Party_B)

            val testData = testDataSession.sendAndReceive<List<StateAndRef<TestState>>>(PartnerNode).unwrap(){it}

            return testData
        }
    }

    @InitiatedBy(TestFlowInitiator::class)
    class Responder(val otherPartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<List<StateAndRef<TestState>>>() {
        companion object {
            object SENDING : ProgressTracker.Step("Sending sign response.")
        }

        override val progressTracker = ProgressTracker(SENDING)
        @Suspendable
        override fun call(): List<StateAndRef<TestState>> {



            val TestInfo = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<TestState>().states.filter { some filtering }.last()

            progressTracker.currentStep = SENDING

            otherPartySession.send(TestInfo)


            return TestInfo
        }
    }
}
```

so through this Party A can access the data of Party B. How can I prevent this if Party B doesn't want to share any of the data with anyone (or with selected people without sharing the state.)

Answer (score 0):

There should be validation in either the contract or in the responder flow to prevent partyB's state from being spent by others.

Comment: Could you pls share some example of that contract ?